# Only return rows where the value appears more than n times

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Suppose I have a table

```
  id            value
------        ---------
  A              123
  A              422
  B              441
  B              986
  B              674
  C              648
```

I need a query which will return only those id's which have 3 or more values associated with them. So, in that case it will only return B.
Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `Group By` clause with [`Having`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx):

```
SELECT id 
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/457fc/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to include the value, you can use window functions to find the ones with three or more rows, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(id CHAR(1), value INT);

INSERT @x SELECT 'A',       123;
INSERT @x SELECT 'A',       422;
INSERT @x SELECT 'B',       441;
INSERT @x SELECT 'B',       986;
INSERT @x SELECT 'B',       674;
INSERT @x SELECT 'C',       648;

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT id, value, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id)
  FROM @x
)
SELECT id FROM x WHERE rn = 3;
```

And you can change the `ORDER BY` to help better determine which `value` is included.

Answer (score 2):

`select id from table group by id having (count(id) >=3)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```